# Сделать оплату или совершить оплату?

Tags: или

Например, сотрудник офиса сказал что совершил оплату на номер или сделал оплату на номер? Как правильно?

Comment: правильно: совершить денежный перевод на карту/по номеру карты - по-простому перевести с карты на карту. https://www.banki.ru/news/daytheme/?id=10979203